# Passing inputs to a function from a list of inputs without hard-coding it in C

Tags: c

Suppose I have a function:

`void add(int a, int b , int c);`

and I have an array which contains 3 integer values:

`int L[] = {1,2,3};`

Now I want to pass these values to add without writing `add(L[0],L[1],L[2]).`
I mean is there a way of creating a Single input from multiple inputs and passing it to the function which will treat that single input as multiple inputs ??.

Comment: `and I have a list`.. you mean an array, right?

Comment: yeah array of a structure .In the structure I have union of multiple types of possible input so an element of the array can be of any type of structure.

Comment: Just pass the array to the function and make it accept an int array as its only parameter.

Comment: What is the problem with writing those 3 parameters out? And what is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: @AyushPandey Maybe something like [This](http://ideone.com/rt7Won)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean something like Python

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

x = (1, 2, 3)
print(foo(*x)) # the '*' does the magic of calling foo with 1, 2, 3
```

then this is not possible in portable C.

What you can do is change the interface of `foo` to accept an array of arguments, e.g.

```
int sum(int *data, int n) {
    int tot = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        tot += data[i];
    }
    return tot;
}
```

can call it with

```
int x[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
int res = sum(x, 4);
```

If you cannot change the function definitions and you have many of them with the same signature what you can do is use function pointers to factor out the call:

```
int sum3(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a+b+c;
}

int mul3(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a*b*c;
}

int call_int_int3(int(*f)(int, int, int), int* args) {
    return f(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
}

...
int data[] = {10, 20, 30};
int sum = call_int_int3(sum3, data);
int prod = call_int_int3(mul3, data);
```

but you will need a different wrapper for each distinct signature (number and type of arguments and type of return value).

Comment: yes exactly I wanted to know the C equivalent of the python code you wrote. I cannot change the function definitions.

Comment: I'd probably change `int n` to `size_t n`, `data` can't be -1 in size after all.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: this is because you think that `unsigned` means "non-negative", a common misconception. That `size_t` was defined as an unsigned type is an historical design bug of C and C++, not something good that you should replicate in new code. For a more detailed explanation see https://youtu.be/4afySnY-XgY

Comment: I'd use `size_t` because I think I'd probabl call `sum(arr, sizeof arr/sizeof *arr);`, and `sizeof` yields `size_t`. In that respect, it makes sense to me that `size_t` is an unsigned type, but I'll check that link out when I've got time. Although it seems to focus only on why it's a mistake in C++

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: actually the mistake was originally in C, inherited and expanded in C++ where `size_t` got used as size type for standard library containers. Unless someone is specifically interested in the `unsigned` semantic where for example `(3u - 4u) > 5u` or in bit manipulation, using them as non-negative values like "size" is conceptually wrong (and dangerous).

Comment: Still need to look at that video, but the way I see it now, if I were to call `sum(arr, sizeof arr/sizeof *arr);` with `sum(int *data, int n);` there is a risk of integer overflow (if `sizeof > INT_MAX`). That's why I commented saying I'd use `size_t`

Answer (score 4):

You could try this

```
int L[] = {1,2,3};
add(L, 3);
```

where

```
void add(int *x, int length)
{
  // use x[0], x[1], etc.
}
```

But I am not sure why you are having problem with your current approach.

Another option would probably be to encapsulate those three integers into a structure and pass the structure along.

Comment: I would add the length of the array in the function parameters

Comment: @TimF Yep was about to do that

Comment: ( To help you understand my case better ). I have a list of function pointers pointing to different functions each one of which has different set of parameters and I have a list containing all those parameters . Now if suppose I want to run a function with a subset of the inputs from the list how do I do it without hard-coding it as there are a lot of function pointers.(Also I cannot change the function definitions of the functions being pointed to by the pointers)

Comment: that list of parameters is an array of a generic base type structure where in the structure I have a union of all possible parameter types.

Comment: @AyushPandey I advise you ask a new question with sufficient details on what you want (e.g. also with code). This question was bit different initially. I find it hard to understand what you want exactly. So as I said, if you don't get satisfactory response on this one, ask another with more details.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Could you add a simple example in your original post ? Like what your functions and parameters lists look like